# Using splice in many occurences of a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string say "This website is blocked by administrator. Please get the admin permissions. You will be allowed only if permission is granted" in a single line.
And this string is not constant.

I have to make it in 3 different lines for the better look and feel. I have used splice method for this.

ex:

```
alertText = alertText1.splice(41, 0, "<br>");
```

This changes only single occurrence of the string where the string breaks into two lines where the second line has a bad look.

Can I know any alternate better methods or any other splice options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use CSS to restrict its width?

Comment: Can you not just insert line-breaks `\n` where you want them?

Comment: I cannot use it since the string is not the constant one.. It is user entered input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new line like this where you want newline

```
"This website is blocked by administrator. \n Please get the admin permissions. \n  You will be allowed only if permission is granted";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prototype your own insert method like below:

```
 function set() {
            var msg = "This website is blocked by administrator. Please get the admin permissions. You will be allowed only if permission is granted";
            msg = msg.insert(40, "\r\n");
            msg = msg.insert(80, "\r\n");
            alert(msg);


        }

        String.prototype.insert = function (index, string) {
            if (index > 0)
                return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substring(index, this.length);
            else
                return string + this;
        };
```

Comment: You are right. But i want to insert line for every 40th, 80th index.

Comment: Hi @user1776130 I have modified my answer, please look at it. You can actually prototype your own insert.

Comment: you can adjust the index 40 & 80 according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to split up your string in lines:

```
function linesString(str,len){
  var ret="<p>"+str.substring(0,len)+"</p>";
  var rest=str.substring(len);
  while(rest.length>len){
    ret=ret+"<p>"+rest.substring(0,len)+"</p>";
    rest=rest.substring(len);
  }
  ret=ret+"<p>"+rest+"</p>";
  return ret;
};

var message="1234567890";
console.log(linesString(message,2));
message="1234567890a";
console.log(linesString(message,2));
```

Or wrap your message in a p tag and define the width of it using style sheets.